# How do I loop through options in the select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I want to loop through options in the select box  that has attribute set as 
"data-status = YES" and select this options  and apply all this options in red color .How can i do that .This "data-status" is written through php

```
<select id ="test1">
<option  value = "1" data-status='YES'>one</option>
<option  value = "2" data-status='NO'>2</option>
<option  value = "3" data-status='YES'>3</option>
<option  value = "4" data-status='YES'>4</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test1 > option:selected').each(function() {
           // alert($(this).text() + ' ' + $(this).val());
           if($(this).data-status==YES"){
                $(this).css()
           }
        });

    });
```

How do i apply the font-weight :bold attribute to the option  that has the data-status =YES
i added it using .addClass("bold")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop, this should do it.

```
   $("#test1 > option[data-status=YES]").css("color","red");
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
$('#test1 option').each(function() {
   // alert($(this).text() + ' ' + $(this).val());
   if($(this).data('status') == 'YES'){
        $(this).css('color','red');
   }
});
```

**demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/6N88x/

---

If you want to also select multiple options then you will need to add the `multiple` attribute to the `select` tag.

```
<select id ="test1" multiple>
```

and change the script to

```
$('#test1 option').each(function() {
   // alert($(this).text() + ' ' + $(this).val());
   if($(this).data('status') == 'YES'){
        $(this)
            .css('color','red')
            .attr('selected',true);
   }
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/6N88x/1/

Comment: How do i increase the Font size  of the option item

Comment: @Derby, you cannot change the font-size on a per-option basis. (*only Firefox allows this*). For Firefox it is `.css('font-size','25px')` http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/6N88x/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($(this).data('status') == 'YES')
```

Comment: I dont have the Selected attribute applied .How do i do it

Comment: @Derby, you should remove it: `$('#test1 > option')`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set the color of an `<option>`, but you can loop through the `<select>` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test1 > option').each(function() {
       if($(this).data('status')=="YES") {
           $(this).html('test'); // or whatever
       }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(this).data-status` to `$(this).attr('data-status')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test1 > option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("status") == "YES";
}).remove(); // or whatever
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xxzLA/

http://api.jquery.com/filter

Comment: How do i apply font style weight bold  to the option that has the data-status ="YES". I tried using addClass but it is not working